# when using C3 library, csv file couldn't be loaded

Tags: csv, data-visualization, c3.js

I tried [this sample code](https://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html), but csv file can't be read.

I put the csv file in the exact location. (same with the directory of index.html)!
Not with csv file (with array data), it perfectly works. 
Has the grammar rule changed or is there a mistake in the code?
If anyone can check if this code works or can help me anyhow, It'll be really appreciated.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/data/c3_test.csv',
        type: 'line'
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        url: '/data/c3_test2.csv'
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data1', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150],
            ['data4', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50],
        ],
        unload: ['data2', 'data3'],
    });
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        rows: [
            ['data2', 'data3'],
            [120, 300],
            [160, 240],
            [200, 290],
            [160, 230],
            [130, 300],
            [220, 320],
        ],
        unload: 'data4',
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: code link: https://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html

Comment: var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        url: '/data/c3_test.csv',
        type: 'line'
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        url: '/data/c3_test2.csv'
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data1', 130, 120, 150, 140, 160, 150],
            ['data4', 30, 20, 50, 40, 60, 50],
        ],
        unload: ['data2', 'data3'],
    });
}, 2000);

Comment: I inlined the code to make it clearer for people to see what you're using. You should add (at least part of) the csv file you are using if it is different to the example. I don't understand the phrase "I put the csv file in the exact location. (same with the directory of index.html)" - you need to clarify what you mean. It sounds like you've everything in the same directory, but if you haven't changed the path in the code, the CSV should be in a a /data/ subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are loading the model using either `file://` or `C:/`, which stays true to the error message as they are not `http://`.

You can confirm that this is the error message that you're getting on your browser's console. But I did what you asked and I got the **"Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/data.csv. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request."** and the csv file could not be loaded either.

So you can either install a webserver in your local PC or upload the model somewhere else and change the url to `http://somehost/path/to/file`

As an alternative, If you're using Chrome, you can try starting it from the terminal with the --allow-file-access-from-files

Browsers don't allow file:// URLs with ajax calls (for security reasons). You need to load your web page through a web server and make your ajax request through that web server using http:// or https://, not file://